# Balls on an Elastic

Tags: animation, physics

I am trying recreate the following phenomenon on Blender and wasn't having much success.
The premise is that two balls are attached to one another with an elastic and they sort of pendulum back and forth. It is made more clear in the video (ignore the first 10s):
https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1ug411773M/

I am fairly new to blender and have been looking things up as I go, and one of my main questions is if this is even possible.
If it is, any ideas on how to model it would be much appreciated. Currently, I am attempting to use two spheres as rigid bodies and a thin box as the elastic by using cloth type simulation.
If not, I am not sure if I'm allowed to ask this, though I was wondering if there are any programs I could use that may be more effective in this case.

Thank you,

Comment: Right off the bat, soft body and other similar deformers must have vertices to work with: They cannot bend single edges into multiple ones.

Comment: After watching the video… I think you should fake it. The physics simulators available with blender are IMO not capable of reproducing this effect.

Comment: This type of cloth simulation is new and isn't implemented in blender.  https://youtu.be/jvBSDXxsgRA?t=333